# Change color of context action menu background for list view in xamarin forms android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, menuitem

[image]

While long press the Viewcell in List View the **Context actions** appears in **xamarin forms (android)**. I need to change the color of the background as red , is there any possible solution?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Create custom object of header menu from List View Context , then change color property.

Comment: Try it: https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/01/04/so-i-played-around-with-xamarin-forms-control-templates/

Comment: i didn't get u @Love-Kesh

Comment: Nope, i think you found it wrongly. I need to change the color of the Context menu color that i highlighted in red color, in your case that says to change colors of the selected item in the listview

Comment: Have you got a solution for that problem?

Comment: Negative. Unfortunately can't able to change colors dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it possibile to change the background color.
On Android, ContentAction are implemented with ActionModes so just set the android:actionModeBackground in the style on your android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/ActionModeColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! To get it to work on all devices, including pre-Lollipop, you remove the android prefix:     `<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/ActionModeColor</item>`